# iOS keyboard is part of development sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have compiled an iOS application using iOS 6 sdk. When i run this application in iOS7 it shows iOS7 default UIAlertView and UIActionSheet i.e. of white color. But the keyboard displayed is of traditional Grey color i.e. of iOS6.

It seems that UIAlertView and UIActionSheet is part of iOS and code just trigger them to display while keyboard is part of development sdk since i compile with sdk7 it shows white keyboard and when i compile with sdk6 it displays grey keyboard in device running iOS7. Please tell is that the case or i am mistaken somewhere

Is there is anyway that i compile code using iOS6 sdk and display white keyboard in iOS7.

Answer (score 2):

No there is not way to get the new iOS 7 keyboard with the iOS 6 SDk.

For compatibility reasons the old keyboard is shown, in iOS 7 the keyboards is translucent and show the underlying view thru it.
To make sure old apps don't break iOS 7 will show the old keyboard when the app is not compiled with the iOS 7 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, external views that you use like UIAlertView are part of the operative system, so calling them will call the new ones, while the keyboard depends on the SDK you use to compile.

I don't think there's any way of showing the new keyboard without compiling with iOS7